# Why does CVPixelBuffer.GetAttributes take an argument of type NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, cvpixelbuffer

In Xamarin.iOS, The method CVPixelBuffer.GetAttributes has a parameter "attributes" of type NSDictionary. For example is might be called like so:

```
myPixelBuffer.GetAttributes(myAttributesDictionary);
```

This makes no sense. Isn't the point of a **Get** function to get the desired value? Why does its signature demand that I pass a value **in**? Why does this method not have 0 parameters, as in:

```
myAttributesDictionary = myPixelBuffer.GetAttributes();
```

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVPixelBuffer.GetAttributes binds the native function [CVPixelBufferCreateResolvedAttributesDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CVPixelBufferCreateResolvedAttributesDictionary)  which takes an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Um, ok... So why does the native function take an argument? (Still same question).

Comment: There we go, thanks for link. To simplify, **the answer to my question is this:** The attributes you pass IN are attributes that may or may not be compatible with the attributes of the pixel buffer. The return value of the function contains (if possible) attributes that are compatible with both your desired/passed-in ones, and the buffer's ones. If such a set cannot be made, the method throws an error. So if you just want to use it like a normal `Get`, don't specify any desired attributes.